# Galois action on blow-ups related to field extensions of infinite degree

Tags: galois-theory, projective-geometry, fields, field-extensions

Let $f(X) \in k[T]$ be irreducible over the field $k$, and separable of finite degree $n$. Then if $\ell$ is the corresponding field extension, we know by Galois theory that $\mathrm{Gal}(\ell/k)$ acts transitively on the $n$ distinct roots of $f(X)$.

My first question most probably is folklore (and/or stupid), but here it is anyway:

> When is this action *sharply transitive* ?

Now suppose $[\ell : k] = 2$, and let $\mathbb{P}^1(\ell)$ be the projective line over $\ell$. Blow it up so as to obtain $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$ (by interpreting the vector space $V(2,\ell)$ corresponding to the line as a $4$-dimensional vector space $V(4,k)$ over $k$); then the point set of $\mathbb{P}^1(\ell)$ becomes a so-called *line spread* $S$ of $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$: a partition of lines. The Galois group $\mathrm{G}(\ell/k)$ naturally acts on $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$, and it fixes each line of $S$, and no point of $\mathbb{P}^3(k)$.

But what if we do the very same construction, but now supposing $[\ell : k] = r$ to be infinite (and forgetting about separability): we obtain a partition $S$ of $\mathbb{P}^{2r - 1}(k)$ in $(r - 1)$-spaces (this can be made precise geometrically), but what about the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\ell/k)$ ?

It still acts on the space, and it fixes every element of the partition, but whereas, in our first example, the point-orbits generically produce generating sets of the lines of $S$, it is less clear to me what happens now, because the fact that the point-orbits generate the $S$-elements, corresponds to the transitive action on the roots in the initial setting of my question.

In other words:

> Can we describe this action on the elements of $S$ in a sensible way,
> perhaps under extra conditions for the field extension ?

Comment: Your first question is indeed easy. Notice that your phrase "the corresponding field extension" is somewhat ambiguous: it could be $k[X] / (f)$ or it could be the splitting field of $f$ over $k$. By what follows (namely that its Galois group acts transitively on the roots), you surely mean the latter. The answer to your first question is now simply: this happens if and only if $f$ splits over $k[X] / (f)$, in other words, if and only if $k[X] / (f)$ is a Galois extension of $k$.

Comment: For your second part: this is not a blow-up, but a Weil restriction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction). If $r$ is infinite, then $\mathbb{P}^{2r-1}(k)$ is not defined as an algebraic variety, although you could still view it as a direct limit of projective spaces, if you wish.

Comment: In addition, I don't understand why you write "forgetting about separability": it seems to me that a natural condition is precisely to assume that $\ell/k$ is Galois, in the sense that $\operatorname{Fix}_\ell(\operatorname{Gal}(\ell/k)) = k$.